# Taking the gradient of $||\nabla f(x) - p||$ with respect to $x$ and $p$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$||\nabla f(x) - p||$$

I'm trying to take the gradients of this with respect to $x$ and $p$.

For $x$, this is what I did:

$$g(x) = ||\nabla f(x) - p || = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}-p_1)^2 + \cdots +(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}-p_n)}\implies\\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} = \frac{2(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}-p_i)\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}}{2\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}-p_1)^2 + \cdots +(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}-p_n)}}$$

however I don't think there's a closed form of writing $\nabla g$. Am I right?

For $p$:

$$h(p) = ||\nabla f(x) -p|| = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}-p_1)^2 + \cdots +(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}-p_n)}\implies \\ \frac{\partial h}{\partial p_i} = \frac{2(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}-p_i)(-1)}{2\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}-p_1)^2 + \cdots +(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}-p_n)}}$$

So $$\nabla h(p) = \frac{p-\nabla f(x)}{||\nabla f(x) -p||}$$

but the result in my book is just $p-\nabla f(x)$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your result for $\nabla h(p)$ seems OK to me upon preliminary inspection.  Maybe your book is wrong--it happens!

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 g &= \nabla f,
\,\,\,\,\,
H=\nabla g,
\,\,\,\,\,
dg = H\,dx \cr
\phi &= \|g-p\| \cr
\phi^2 &= \|g-p\|^2 = (g-p):(g-p) \cr
}$$
Take the differential of the last expression and solve for $d\phi$.
$$\eqalign{
2\phi\,d\phi &= 2 (g-p):(dg-dp) = 2 (g-p):(H\,dx-dp) \cr
 d\phi &= \phi^{-1}H(g-p):dx + \phi^{-1}(p-g):dp \cr
}$$
The desired gradients can be plucked out of this differential. 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= H(g-p)\phi^{-1},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial p}  = (p-g)\phi^{-1} \cr\cr
}$$
In some of the steps above, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and property $H^T=H$ was used to simplify some expressions.

So either the book was wrong, or you made a mistake transcribing the problem.